# Consider the equation $y'(x)+ay(x)=f(x)$ where $a<0$ and $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in(-\infty,\infty),M>0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the equation
$$y'(x)+ay(x)=f(x)$$
Where $a<0$ and $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in(-\infty,\infty),M>0$

(a) Prove that there exists a unique solution which is bounded on the whole real line.

(b) Prove that the solution of (a) is periodic when $f(x)$ is assumed to be periodic.

I've managed to show that
$$y(x)=e^{-ax}\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{as}f(s)ds+c\right)$$
But I needed to assume that $f$ is integrable in the domain and that show existence but the part of bounded I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is wrong. For example, let $a=-1,f(x)=0$ and then the equation becomes
$$ y'-y=0. $$
This one has solution $y=ce^x$ which is unbounded in the whole real line for $c\neq0$.

Update: If $f$ is nonconstant, let $a=-1, f(x)=\sin(x)$. The the equation becomes
$$ y'-y=\sin(x). $$
The solution is
$$ y=ce^x-\frac12[\sin(x)+\cos(x)]. $$
Thus the solution is unbounded for the whole real line for $c\neq0$.

Comment: Thanks and if we assume that $f$ is not constant and continous?

Comment: @ronkurman, see the update.

Comment: thanks :) i will check this